# How can I transfer different JPG's and INT's over ObjectOutputStream as one package

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, objectoutputstream

I want to do a screen motion detection algorithm. 
I lay a grid over the desktop screen and only want to transfer the parts of the screen that have changed.

I have Integer values to determine the position of the piece in the grid and a Array of Bytes that store the JPG information.

At a time it can be that I have to transfer 1 piece of the grid and at another time it can be all pieces of the screen.
I want to transfer these information as one "package" over `ObjectOutputStream`.

How can I create a way to pack these variables together and send them? I guess it should be some kind of array or an Object that contains an array.

Comment: Just create a serializable object class containing whatever it is you want it to contain.

Comment: what have you tried so far? have you tried to transfer a dynamic amount of data?

Comment: My consideration was so far that I create a custom serializable object that contains the Int and Byte Array. Is that the "right" way?

Comment: nobody can say what is right - but i think a serializable object will work for your purpose...

Comment: Ok it works so far but I can't determine if it is the custom object I created. Why it is not possible to check if the received Object is an instance of my custom class "Point"? obj = cObjectInputStream.readObject(); if (obj instanceof Point) {

Comment: does your client app have this class in it's project (classpath)? can you import that subclass?

Comment: @Felix It ***is*** possible. What makes you think otherwise? What's the *actual* problem you're trying to solve here?